# How can we use map instead of flatMapMerge in Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I'm migrating a Webflux codebase that uses Reactor types (Mono and Flux) to Kotlin coroutines.

Consider this excerpt with `Flux`:

```
fun getClientProjects(clientId: String) : Flux<Project> {
    return projectReactiveRepository.findByClientId(clientId)
}

fun getAllProjects() : Flux<Project> {
    return clientRepository.findAll().flatMap { client -> getProjects(client.id) }
}
```

It gets all clients and for each of them invokes a reactive repository concurrently, subscribing eagerly to the nested Fluxes.

This could be translated to coroutines as shown below:

```
suspend fun getClientProjects(clientId: String) : Flow<Project> {
    return projectReactiveRepository.findByClientId(clientId).asFlow()
}

fun getAllProjects() : Flow<Project> {
    return clientRepository.findAll().asFlow().flatMapMerge { client -> getProjects(client.id) }
}
```

[Flow.flatMapMerge javadoc states](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html):

> Note that even though this operator looks very familiar, we discourage
> its usage in a regular application-specific flows. Most likely,
> suspending operation in map operator will be sufficient and linear
> transformations are much easier to reason about.

How could I replace flatMapMerge with map and keep the concurrency of the nested Flows?

Comment: I don't think they are suggesting there is equivalent code for `flatMapMerge` that can be done with `map`, but they are are trying to discourage concurrency of Flows in the first place, because *" linear transformations are much easier to reason about"*. I'm not really sure though. I don't see what's so hard about reasoning a `flatMapMerge`. If you just need flattened data, I don't see how it's any harder to understand than doing it sequentially.